# Blue prism Spying HTML mode issue (spied elements are moved)

Tags: html, automation

I have an issue spying HTML elements, with HTML mode. I am able to identify all of the elements, but it seems like identified object has been "moved down-left".
(See example below - Google Search button has been spied, and green rectangle is moved)
I'm pretty sure that element is spied correctly, becouse even if I add manually correct element ID (which is unique), - rectangle is still moved.
All actions (e.g. click centre) are realted to green rectangle. (so in case below it will not work, becouse its centre is below bottom of Google Search button)

[image]

Any ides will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your screen text resolution (in windows) to 100% (it's usually in 200%). Log off, log back on, and try again.

After logging back on, you can either increase it again or change resolution if the text is too small.

Answer (score 1):

Havan, thank's for support, actually you were close enough. The real answer was more trivial - my default browser zoom was set to 120%, so the solution was to change it to 100%

Answer (score 0):

try to include/check 'path' attribute in attribute list after spying. Its better not to depend on resolution.